XDrawRectangle misses bottom-right pixel
I have a wrapper function to implement XDrawRectangle() in X11/Xlib.h in Linux.  But it's not plotting the bottom right pixel.  Is there something wrong with this function?
EDIT: minimal reproducible code at bottom of post.
X11 version is:
$ dpkg -l | grep libx11-dev
ii  libx11-dev:amd64 2:1.7.5-1ubuntu0.3 amd64 X11
client-side library (development headers)

This is what appears in X11/Xlib.h, as installed just recently:
extern int XDrawRectangle(
Display*        /* display */,
Drawable        /* d */,
GC          /* gc */,
int         /* x */,
int         /* y */,
unsigned int    /* width */,
unsigned int    /* height */
);

My header file:
/* Draw a rectangle at (x,y) with width (w) and height (h) */
void gfx_rect( int x, int y, unsigned int w, unsigned int h );

My code file for it:
/* Draw a rectangle at (x,y) with width (w) and height (h) */
void gfx_rect( int x, int y, unsigned int w, unsigned int h ) {
    XDrawRectangle(gfx_display,gfx_window,gfx_gc,x,y,w,h);
}

My simple call:
const int offset = 10;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

gfx_rect(x+offset, y+offset, 20, 20);

What is drawn:

Note that the bottom-right pixel is missing.
EDIT: Here's the [minimal-but-not-so-small]* file that reproduces the problem and the compile command:

gcc main.c -o fontview -lX11 -lm

#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Open a new graphics window. */
void gfx_open( int width, int height, const char *title );
/* Wait for the user to press a key or mouse button. */
char gfx_wait();

static Display *gfx_display=0;
static Window  gfx_window;
static GC      gfx_gc;

int main() {
    char c;

    // Open a new window for drawing.
    gfx_open(532,276,"Font Viewer");

    XDrawRectangle(gfx_display,gfx_window,gfx_gc,10,10,20,20);
    
    while(1) {
        // Wait for the user to press a character.
        c = gfx_wait();

        // Quit if it is the letter q.
        if(c=='q') break;
    }

    return 0;
}

/* Open a new graphics window. */
void gfx_open( int width, int height, const char *title ) {
    gfx_display = XOpenDisplay(0);
    if(!gfx_display) {
        fprintf(stderr,"gfx_open: unable to open the graphics window.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int blackColor = BlackPixel(gfx_display, DefaultScreen(gfx_display));
    int whiteColor = WhitePixel(gfx_display, DefaultScreen(gfx_display));

    gfx_window = XCreateSimpleWindow(gfx_display, DefaultRootWindow(gfx_display), 0, 0, width, height, 0, blackColor, blackColor);

    XSelectInput(gfx_display, gfx_window, StructureNotifyMask|KeyPressMask|ButtonPressMask);

    XMapWindow(gfx_display,gfx_window);

    gfx_gc = XCreateGC(gfx_display, gfx_window, 0, 0);

    XSetForeground(gfx_display, gfx_gc, whiteColor);

    // Wait for the MapNotify event
    for(;;) {
        XEvent e;
        XNextEvent(gfx_display, &e);
        if (e.type == MapNotify)
            break;
    }
}

/* Wait for the user to press a key or mouse button. */
char gfx_wait() {
    XEvent event;

    while(1) {
        XNextEvent(gfx_display,&event);

        if(event.type==KeyPress) {
            return XLookupKeysym(&event.xkey,0);
        } else if(event.type==ButtonPress) {
            return event.xbutton.button;
        }
    }
}


How the heck did someone do this in 10 lines?!


Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] and also include details of your OS/platform etc.

Can't reproduce that. My attempt to do the same show a well closed rectangle. But obviously you did some operations on GC before (we really need that [mre] to answer). At least, set the foreground color. We cannot know without the [mre] if there isn't already something on the drawable, if there isn't a Function set in GC that could explain that, or a mask...

I should include all files?

Instead of that follow the link, read and then apply the idea described there. In short: enough to demonstrate, nothing else.

Re. "I should include all files?": you should provide a [mcve] -- not your whole application source code.  A simple, minimal demo needn't be more that a few dozen lines.

You should include a minimal example. That is with all the needed lines (including #include <X11/Xlib.h> or Display *dpy=XOpenDisplay("") and the like. But only the needed lines. My own code to try to reproduce your bug contains 10 lines. Your should be a few line bigger, I guess, since there must be something else. Or if those 10 lines reproduce your error on your machine, that would prove that it is related to your plateform, not to your code. But it should contain only the XSetFunction or things like that.

And that means, that, to produce those 10+ lines of [mre], you will have to try to remove progressively every non pertinent things from your code. And in the process of doing so, it is very likely that you will find which part of your code, once removed, suppress the problem. Which will allow you, either to solve the question yourself, or to ask a more accurate question on why that particular line of code cause that problem

So, it is some work to do, I know. But that is your job. We can't do it for you. And anyway, as is, without any code, we can't tell nothing more than what I've already said: on my computer, XDrawRectangle doesn't forget any pixel.

@chrslg I know it's my responsibility.  I was just asking.

Added code in original post.  I'll note that the "gfx" code is not mine, but was obtained from here: https://www3.nd.edu/~dthain/courses/cse20211/fall2013/gfx/

Well, I confirm then: I can't reproduce. Your code produce a normal rectangle without any missing pixel here. So we are back to the other question @G.M. asked: plateform, library version, etc. I use a real X11 server (I say "real", because nowadays there are many "wayland with X11 compatibility", or X11 on windows, X11 on mac, etc.). Are you also?

Also, you may try to compile and run your code on a remote machine (a droplet, or a ec2 instance, or anytbhing), using your local PC as DISPLAY (tunneling X with ssh -X if needed). Does the problem still appear then? (If yes, that means that the problem is probably on your server, unless you are unlucky enough to have the same problem, client-side on that droplet/ec2/etc).

@chrslg I don't know what a "real X11 server" is.  This is a Dell PC running Linux Mint 21.1.  Problem also exists on laptop running same OS.

Or the opposite experiment: use another server, preferably unrelated to yours (so, for example, avoid Xnest that is probably compiled from the same batch of code as your server), like a VNC server (maybe even on a remote machine). And run your exact same client on your local machine (the one on which you saw the problem), but using that other server as DISPLAY. If the problem is still there, then you have a problem client-side (unless you are unlucky enough to have the same problem on your other server).

@chrslg I have no idea what any of that is, sorry.

"real" was between quote. It is just that Wayland is spreading faster than Covid in 2020. And lot of people have nowadays a wayland server, with a X11 compatibility layer (so a wayland client, that acts as a X11 server, and draw whatever it is asked to draw on the wayland screen)

X11 is a client-server protocol. You have a X11 server (running on the machine whose screen displays the rectangle). It is a server. Like a web server is: it is waiting for clients to connect from internet (most of the time, locally, of course, not really internet), and send request. Requests are 'draw a line here, fill a rectangle there, etc'. So, to write a program that displays some graphics, you write a "client". A program that connect to a X server, and ask it to draw things for you.

But because you don't want to play with some sort of API (and that API is not as easy as a web API to use, furthermore) and connect to some sockets, writing bytes and stuff, well, implementing a whole protocol, X11 provides, in addition to the server, a library to help writing such clients. This is the library you use (libX11, with functions such as XDrawRectangle. So what XDrawRectangle does is not literally drawing a rectangle. It is sending a message to the server to ask it to draw a rectangle.

That is, in a nutshell (and purist are dying now, reading me) what X11 architecture is. So,when your run your code, a pixel is missing. When I run your code no pixel is missing. So there is a difference somewhere between our machines. But two things could be that difference

X11 version added to original post


Your X11 server (the thing that handle the graphical screen, that you run as soon as you exit the 80×25 text console when you boot your machine) behaves differently as mine.
Your X11 client library (the library you used to compile your program, and that I used to compile it here) is different.


So, to try to know if your server or your x11 library is the culprit, I suggest to try separately. By running your code in another machine, while asking to do the display on your machine (that is the whole point of X) you can test your X11 server alone. By trying on the opposite to run your code on your machine, but redirecting the display on another server (for example the one embedded in a VNC server) you can test your libX11 alone.

If you have the problem on two different machines, we can rule out material problem (that was very unlikely from the start anywauy). But since the two machines use the same OS, that may mean that Linux Mint X11 is the culprit. But still, it doesn't say if it is the X11 server of Linux mint, or the libX11 of linux Mint

Also «  How the heck did someone do this in 10 lines?!» : without defining functions for a single call (not saying that it is wrong to do so. Just that I didn't, especially for a quick experiment). By not checking return values (bad, but, well, just an experiment). By using inline values for black and white pixels (0 and 0xffffff) — again, bad generally speaking, since, theoretically, that depends on the machine. I practice, I know that those are black and white. By not using a event loop to wait for window to map (just blocking XSync)

And not using a full event loop neither (I don't really need to have the ability to quit with "Q" to see a rectangle) just a call to XNextEvent, without any XSelectInput to force a refresh and waiting).

I've removed that code since (replaced by yours). But roughly, taht would goes Display *dpy=XOpenDisplay(""); GC gc=DefaultGC(dpy, 0); Window rw=DefaultRootWindow(dpy); win=XCreateSimpleWindow(dpy, rw, 100, 100, 100, 100, 0,0,0); XSync(dpy, 1); XSetForeground(dpy, gc, 0xffffff); XDrawRectangle(dpy, win, gc, 10, 10, 10, 10); XEvent evt; XNextEvent(dpy, &evt); (just typing directly in comment, so probably a mistake somewhere. I never type more than 3 lines of code without an error any way. But that's the spirit of it. As you see, that is 8 lines. Plus some overhead (#include, int main...

(I forgot the XMapWindow. So 9). Not claiming at all (on the contrary) that is a correct way to code. Obviously, not checking value of dpy is bad. Assuming 0xffffff is white is bad. Using XSync is clearly not advised by its own manpage. But, well, for a [mre] it did its job: that experiment showed me that no pixel is missing when I XDrawRectangle
